# Errors occur when calling print(List<T> a, T b) with different T class

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to learn Java Generics, and found the following code.

```
public static <T> void print(T a, T b){
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    print(new ArrayList<String>(), 1);
}
```

Which works with no problem.

However when I change `print` method to the following, it gives me compiling errors.

```
public static <T> void print(List<T> a, T b){
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Error:

```
GenericTest.java:9: error: method print in class GenericTest cannot be applied to given types;
  print(new ArrayList<String>(), 1);
    ^
  required: List<T>,T
  found: ArrayList<String>,int
  reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that argument type int conforms to formal parameter type T
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>print(List<T>,T)
1 error
```

Can anyone help me understand the errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing you should understand is that, with the following method signature

```
public static <T> void print(T a, T b)
```

Both `T` **must** be the same type, that is to say both `a` and `b` will have the same infered type.

So why does it work for `new ArrayList<String>()` and `1`? Because both parameters can actually be represented as [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), which is the nearest common super type of `ArrayList` and `Integer`:

- [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) implements the `Serializable` interface.
- `1` can be boxed into an [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), which is also `Serializable`.

So in this case, the compiler will infer `T` as `Serializable`.

---

In the second case, with the signature

```
public static <T> void print(List<T> a, T b)
```

There is no common super type `T` that would be valid for both `List<String>` and `Integer`. It is true that both `String` and `Integer` are `Serializable`, but since [generics aren't polymorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/1743880), it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you also explain why it's resolved to `Serializable` and not any other common super type?

Comment: @Codebender Because it is the nearest common super type between `ArrayList` and `Integer`. `Object` would be one level up in the hierarchy.

Comment: I don't get how the hierarchy is formed between Interface & Class (I will ask a new question about that), but eclipse shows it's resolved to Serializable (+1 for that)...

Comment: @Codebender To put it simply, make a tree of the hierarchy (in Eclipse, press F4 on the type and show supertype hierarchy) and add 1 each time you go up one level. The type that will be common to ArrayList and Integer with the lowest count is Serializable.

Comment: @Tunaki I just read Java Doc about "Erasure of Generic Methods" that "Because `T` is unbounded, the Java compiler replaces it with `Object`" Reference: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html

Comment: @Xin, erasure doesn't have anything to do with your scenario (Yes at runtime it will be Object because of erasure)... Your's is about inference...

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks for the quick answer. I will look into inference. (+1)

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** It doesn't get resolved to Object as I had mentioned but to Serializable. [See Tunaki's correct answer for the reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34944269/2775450).

In your first case, `T` is resolved to the **most specific** type which can refer to both your arguments.

And in your example, it will get resolved to <strike>`Object`</strike> `Serializable`, since `ArrayList` and `Integer` are both <strike>`Object`</strike> `Serializable` sub-types.

But in your second example, you have a `List<T>` as the parameter...

Now, when you call it with `ArrayList<String>`, the type `T` is resolved to a `String`. It cannot be resolved to any other type because an <strike>`ArrayList<Object>`</strike> `ArrayList<Serializable>` is **NOT** a supertype of `ArrayList<String>`

Answer (score 3):

You call the method in following ways :

```
print(new ArrayList<String>(), "SimpleString");
```

or

```
print(new ArrayList<Integer>(),5)
```

because `<T>` is a type and it cannot be both String and integer at same time.

Your call could work if you do something like this :

```
public static <T, K> void print(List<T> a, K b){
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    print(new ArrayList<String>(),1);
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer as it's the only one having code with 2 type parameters. As the syntax isn't necessarily intuitive to a beginner. The example clarifies how to use it. Nice work. Will +1 tommorow (vote limit).