# Java genrics upper bound not working

Tags: java

I have a simple generic function

```
static <T, V extends T> boolean isIn(T x, V[] y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
        if (x.equals(y[i]))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

and I am callling this funciton with following paramters

```
Integer nums[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
isIn("abc",nums);
```

Shouldn't the above code have compile time error as T is upper bound to V. But it compiles without errors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34944269/2775450

Comment: what i am trying to achieve with this function is that if i pass first argument as say integer the array type should also be integer

Comment: The compiler can infer `T` as a supertype of `Integer` and `String`. For example it would work if `T=Object`. Actually, a more specific type is inferred, something like `Serializable & Comparable<? extends Serializable & Comparable<? extends ...> >` (an [infinite type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7-600) )