# Static generic methods

Tags: java, generics

Can you explain why the following works?

```
public class GenericsTest<T> {

    public void doSomething(T v1, T v2) {

    }

    public static <T> void doSomethingStatic(T v1, T v2) {

    }

    public static <T> void doSomethingStaticList(List<T> v1, List<T> v2)
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericsTest<String> gt = new GenericsTest<>();

        // OK
        gt.doSomething("abc", "abc");

        // Not OK
        gt.doSomething(1, "abc");

        // OK
        doSomethingStatic(1, 2);

        // Still OK
        doSomethingStatic(1, "abc");

        // So why is this not OK?
        List<String> list1=new LinkedList<>();
        List<Integer> list2=new LinkedList<>();
        doSomethingStaticList(list1,list2);
    }
}
```

`T v1, T v2` should be the same type in `doSomethingStatic`, but I'm still able to pass different types(integer and string).

If `doSomethingStatic()` takes a common super class by default, why doesn't `doSomethingStaticList()` work with different types?

Comment: In `public static <T> void doSomethingStatic(T v1, T v2) {`, the type variable is unnecessary: it's semantically identical to `public static void doSomethingStatic(Object v1, Object v2) {`.

Comment: To the update: because there is no `T` that would match both types. The only type that would match both lists is the raw type `List`, but there is no valid `List<T>`.

Comment: In the case of the lists, what superclass type would `T` take to make them both valid? Don't forget that generics are invariant, and you can't assign a `List<Integer>` to a `List<Object>`.

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/34944269/1743880

Comment: @Tony Changing or adding a new question after it has already been answered is not a good idea, because you are unlikely to get an answer. Anyway, in case of lists, in short `List<Integer>` is not a subclass of `List<Object>`. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In non-static case you define `T` as `String` when you create instance of `GenericsTest`. Hence passing an `int` will give compile error. If you did `gt.doSomething(1, 2)` it would fail as well.

In static case, you don't define `T` manually, it is derived from parameters. It will be the first common superclass of both classes - which in this case is `Object`. You might want to use bounded wildcard, e.g. `<T extends Number>` or `<T extends CharSequence>`.

Note that you have two different `T`s here:

- `GenericsTest<T>`
- `public static <T> void doSomethingStatic(T v1, T v2)`

The declaration of generic parameter is whenever you write `<T>`. You can use different letters in this case to avoid confusion.

Comment: The `<T>` in the static method is complete standalone/separated from the class itself. So T will fall back to the first common supertype of v1 and v2, which is Object in this case. If one does not include `<T>` the compiler would interprete it as the `T` of the class and since the Method is static, this is illegal.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The question was edited to describe another scenario ~25 minutes after I posted this answer. I gave short explanation + link in the comment on the question.

Answer (score 14):

This works because `T` in your static method is his **own** type parameter, not the `T` parameter for **instance** that used in your **member method**. Rename it to clarify:

```
public static class GenericsTest<T> {

    public void doSomething(T v1, T v2) {

    }

    public static <V> void doSomethingStatic(V v1, V v2) {

    }
//...
```

So in case of `doSomething(...)` your instance type parameter value is `String` so it's an error. In case of static `doSomethingStatic(...)` value of type parameter is different:

```
GenericsTest.doSomethingStatic(1, "abc"); //ok
GenericsTest.<Object>doSomethingStatic(1, "abc"); //ok
GenericsTest.<String>doSomethingStatic(1, "abc"); //not ok
new GenericsTest<String>().doSomething(1, "abc"); //not ok
```

Answer (score 2):

First a bit of theory:

- Generic methods are methods that introduce their own type parameters [Java Tutorials - Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)
- Type inference is a Java compiler's ability to look at each method invocation and corresponding declaration to determine the type argument (or arguments) that make the invocation applicable [Java Tutorials - Type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)

So what happen:

- when a generic expression precede the return value then a new generic type variable is "declared". So the T of the class declaration is different (for the compiler) from the T of the method declaration.
- the compiler apply type inference and in your example it determine that the suitable type to apply method invocation is Object

You can try also this example without static method:

```
public class GenericsTest<T> {

  public void doSomething(T v1, T v2) {

  }

  public <T> void doSomething2(T v1, T v2) {

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericsTest<String> gt = new GenericsTest<>();

    // ok
    gt.doSomething("abc", "abc");

    // Not ok
    gt.doSomething(1, "abc");

    // ok
    gt.doSomething2(1, 2);

    // Still ok
    gt.doSomething2(1, "abc");

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In static case, you don't define T manually, it is derived from parameters. 
In the case doSomethingStaticList(list1,list2) where list1 is String generic List while list2 is Integer generic List. Compiler inference algorithm won't be able to recognize because List and List doesn't belong to any common type.